# C# Razor partial page dynamically update label text

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, .net-5

I have a C# Razor application in .Net5. Within this application I have a partial page without a model. In it I need to dynamically assign the text of a link. However, without a model I'm not sure how best to go about this.

The value is one that will stay the same for the duration that a user will be in the application. However, the value will be different for different users.

Could I hold the value in a cookie, and retrieve this within the partial page? Or is there a better approach?

Comment: Are you using MVC? If so you have ViewBag, ViewData or TempData. Otherwise, if it is a webform application, use Session and server side tags.

Comment: I tried using TempData, but this only works once. And as the partial page is queried from the _Layout page - which I forgot to mention, it means that on subsequent page loads, the value has been lost. Unless I reset it on every page, but I'm not going to do that.

Comment: Find out how to use Session in MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set and get session in razor view/pages like below:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
@{
    HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString("KeyName", "aaaa"); 
}
@HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("KeyName")
```

Be sure register session and HttpContextAccessor in Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    //...
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddSession();
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseSession();  //be sure add this...

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
}
```